# Nodejs req.query.token undefined from url

Tags: node.js

Good day,

Can anyone help me with this question, I send email to user with link which have token and email in it:

```
<p>To reset your password, please click the link <a href="http://localhost:5000/reset-password?token=' + token + '&email=' + email + '">link</a></p>
```

So with following code I'm trying to set new password for user:

```
router.post('/reset-password', authController.resetPassword);
```

```
exports.resetPassword = async (req, res, next) => {
    let token = req.query.token;
    let email = req.query.email;
    console.log(token);
 console.log(email);
...
```

Page form:

```
<form action="/auth/reset-password" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password1" id="newPassword" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Naujas slaptažodis" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password2" id="newPasswordConfirm" name="passwordConfirm" class="form-control" placeholder="Pakartoti nauja slaptažodį" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-theme btn-block btn-form">Patvirtinti</button>
</form>
```

So my problem is that req.query.token return for me undefined.

Probably problem is that when user press submit, it send to new link (http://localhost:5000/auth/reset-password) which don't have token and email in new url.

How should I transfer it from my email url to new url, or maybe there is something else what I can do?

Thank you

Comment: The clickable link will perform a GET request, but your handler is for a POST request. And your form makes a POST request but doesn't pass any query parameters.

Comment: I have tried change router.post to router.get and method="POST" to method="GET", still same.

Comment: You need two distinct routes: one GET route that handles the clickable link and one POST route that handles the form. Only the GET route will have `req.query.token` defined.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what should I do. Could you show an example?

Comment: Ohh I think I got it, I will post answer to this question if everything is alright.

Comment: Sure, you can answer your own question :D

Comment: Nop, cant find a solution, too hard for me to find out, dont have enough skills for that.

Answer (score 0):

I managed today to fix it, so if any one have familiar problem do as robertklep told me.